# How can I change the typeface used in my theorem environments

Tags: fonts, theorems

I know I can change the properties of theorem environments (using `\newtheoremstyle`, as shown below), but how can I change the font type from Computer Modern to Times New Roman? That change should be local: Times should only be used within theorem environments.

Note: I compile my document with `pdflatex`.

```
\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle} % name
        {\topsep}                    % Space above
        {\topsep}                    % Space below
        {\itshape}                   % Body font
        {}                           % Indent amount
        {\scshape\color{blue}}                   % Theorem head font
        {:}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
        {.5em}                       % Space after theorem head
        {}  % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
```

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document

Comment: i saw that page before, but how can i adjust that information to the "theorem environment".

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Related to the linked question in the comment by Jubobs [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document) , you can use:

```
\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle} % name
        {\topsep}                    % Space above
        {\topsep}                    % Space below
        {\itshape\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}                   % Body font
        {}                           % Indent amount
        {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\scshape\color{blue}}                   % Theorem head font
        {:}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
        {.5em}                       % Space after theorem head
        {}  % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
```

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle} % name
        {\topsep}                    % Space above
        {\topsep}                    % Space below
        {\itshape\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}                   % Body font
        {}                           % Indent amount
        {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\scshape\color{blue}}                   % Theorem head font
        {:}                          % Punctuation after theorem head
        {.5em}                       % Space after theorem head
        {}  % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{lemma}[foo bar]
\lipsum[3]
\end{lemma}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```